# Spring form insert data in model object inside base domain model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a model like this:

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private City city;

    //Getter - setters
}

public class City{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    //Getter - setters
}
```

Now on JSP I want to show a form for User model, which should ask for user's city in a dropdown, and corresponding city object should get stored in `city` object in `User` model.

For normal fields, I know we can write something like this:

```
<form:input path="name" />
```

But how can we bind a model object inside our base model? And how Spring will know, which object it should store in that after user selects any city?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, you need @modelAttribute in your controller method (or simply add it to model) on loading the form and use  in your case path should be city.name

Your question is more like how to reference a submodel, spring follows the bean path, in your case, if you wanna post a city with user object, you just need to do this

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
    <form:input path="city.name" />
    <form:input path="attribute of user" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a little snippet? I am not sure how exactly are you referring it to.

Comment: @abhi I'm with phone, but I will try